# How to use drag and drop applyFilter

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to understand the proper syntax for this jqyoui-draggable option. Here's what I've tried:
jqyoui-draggable="{animate:false, index: $index, applyFilter: 'myFilter'}"

If I have the scope function, myFilter, it does get called, but I get the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

So it wants to operate on some array, but I don't know how to pass that array as a parameter to the filter. I've tried:
'myFilter(anArray)'
'myFilter:anArray)'
'myFilter[anArray]'

All generate the error:
Undefined is not a function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by declaring a scope variable that is set via an 'onStart' function which takes the array as a parameter. I use this scope variable in the filter function. Seems to be more work than should be necessary, but it works.

In the html markup

jqyoui-draggable="{onStart: 'setDragTarget(myArray)', applyFilter: 'myFilter'}"

In the controller:

$scope.dragTarget = ''

$scope.SetDragTarget - function(dragTarget){

$scope.dragTarget = dragTarget;
}

$scope.myFilter = function(){
 return $filter('orderBy')($scope.dragTarget, 'fieldName');

}

That's it! If there's an easier way, please feel free to comment.